# Create kubernetes secret from .json file

Tags: kubernetes

I have a json file with some keys like this:

```
{
  "a":"someval"
  "b":"someval"
  .. more keys
}
```

How do I add these keys to a secret in kubernetes?

When I try `$ kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-file=file.json` it returns a secret containing the file, but **I want to map the contents of the file to the secret**, not add the file as a secret.

Output:

`$ kubectl get secret mysecret -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  file.json: #base64 encoded stuff here.
kind: Secret
```

---

**Wanted output:**

`$ kubectl get secret mysecret -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  a: someval
  b: someval
kind: Secret
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't want the contents of a secret to be encoded, you could use a ConfigMap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these steps

```
kubectl proxy --port 8000 &  
curl localhost:8000/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets 

curl localhost:8000/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets \
  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"metadata":{"name":"mytest"},"stringData":{"a":"test","b":"test","c":"test"}}'

master $ curl localhost:8000/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/mytest{
  "kind": "Secret",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "mytest",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/mytest",
    "uid": "55736602-725e-11e9-b3a2-0242ac110034",
    "resourceVersion": "2948",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-05-09T13:28:29Z"
  },
  "data": {
    "a": "dGVzdA==",
    "b": "dGVzdA==",
    "c": "dGVzdA=="
  },
  "type": "Opaque"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have flat (not nested) JSON then try this (assuming you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) tool installed):

```
kubectl create secret generic test --from-env-file <(jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" YOUR_FILE.json)
```

Comment: For anyone running into trouble getting this to work, note that only the lefthand parentheses are escaped in the jq query: `\(foo)`

Comment: This only works if the secret does not contain new lines. If you have e.g. a PEM formatted private key, this method will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Create a json file like this (note that secret values must be base64-encoded):

```
{ 
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {},
    "name": "mytest",
    "namespace": "default"
  },
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Secret",
  "data": {
    "a": "dGVzdA==",
    "b": "dGVzdA=="
  }
}
```

Then pass it into kubectl create:

```
kubectl create -f secrets-file.json
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `--from-literal`:

```
kubectl create secret generic secretname --from-literal "someJsonKey=$(cat somejsonfile.json)"
```

Then you can recover the data with

```
kubectl get secret secretname -o 'go-template={{ .data.someJsonKey | base64decode }}'
```